# How to change output PDF filename(LuaLatex)

Tags: pdf, luacode, lualatex-dev

I'm using Lualatex and looking for a way to change the **name** of the output PDF generated. Can I do this via command line arguments when calling Lualatex to compile my document? or can it be set somewhere inside the .tex file that is being compiled ( in a Linux env)?

Comment: Search this site for jobname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command to compile `old.tex` to `new.pdf`:

```
lualatex --jobname=new old
```

To generate the pdf file in the directory `dest`, just run

```
lualatex --jobname=new --output-directory=dest old
```

under the assumption that `./dest` is an existing directory.

Comment: thanks....can I also change the location to write the output pdf to somewhere other than the project directory

Comment: @24suns, certainly. please see my updated answer.